# International meeting planner allowing to propose several slots

Tags: gratis, calendar, time-management, saas, meetings

All online meeting planners I could find have **only one start/end**.
What I want instead:

[image: Meeting planner with several slots]

Requirements:

- Each person can enter their available slots, they are shown as seen above.
- Each person sees days/hours in their own timezone.
- Available gratis as an online service
- No need to provide anyone's email or other information, only the slots
- At least 2 attendees, bonus for support for more

Tried:

- Doodle [shows timeslots as a list](http://doodle.com/gimg/select-times.png), not in a days+hours view like above, not intuitive.
- agreeadate.com requires your email address
- TimeBridge requires Google authentication and wants to "*Know the list of people in your circles*"

Answer (score 1):

[NeedToMeet](http://www.needtomeet.com) is the closest webapp I have found so far, even though it is not perfect:

1. On the homepage, click "Schedule a meeting"
2. Enter any meeting name, "1" is OK
3. Click "Select times"
4. Fill with the mouse:

[image: NeedToMeet select times]

5. Click "Invite attendees"
6. Click "Copy link"
7. Send that link to the other attendee
8. When the other attendee opens the link, the default view is very user-unfriendly, so the attendee must click "Select via calendar" to get a view similar to the screenshot above.
9. The attendees can fill their own slots **within the slots of the first person**.

Gratis. It correctly detects and applies your timezone.

Drawbacks:

- Two attendees maximum
- Sometimes user-unfriendly, see step 8 above